# FBSDKGraphRequest does not redirect to app after login

Tags: ios, facebook, swift

I am using FBSDKGraphRequest to implement Facebook login in my iOS app.

But after the login is done and the user confirms, I am not redirected to my app.

Here is my code:

```
FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters:   nil).startWithCompletionHandler({
        (connection, result, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            println("\(result)")
        } else {
            println("\(error)")
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("home", sender: self)
        }
    })
```

Comment: If you are using Facebook sdk 4.x then refer to start coding section of https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your appdelegate :

```
import UIKit

import FBSDKCoreKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    }
    func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {    
        FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()
    }
    func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
    }
}
```

In your view controller :

```
import UIKit
import FBSDKLoginKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var dict : NSDictionary!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    @IBAction func btnFBLoginPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        var fbLoginManager : FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
        fbLoginManager .logInWithReadPermissions(["email"], handler: { (result, error) -> Void in
            if (error == nil){
                var fbloginresult : FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult = result
                if(fbloginresult.grantedPermissions.containsObject("email"))
                {
                    self.getFBUserData()
                    fbLoginManager.logOut()
                }
            }
        })
    }

    func getFBUserData(){
        if((FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()) != nil){
            FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email"]).startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in
                if (error == nil){
                    self.dict = result as NSDictionary
                    println(result)
                    println(self.dict)
                    NSLog(self.dict.objectForKey("picture")?.objectForKey("data")?.objectForKey("url") as String)
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Add properties in your plist.info file.

[image]

Add URL Types, FacebookAppID, and FacebookDisplayName Properties

For more you can go through the steps of https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started

Answer (score 0):

You have to add handle URL code in your app delegate like this-

```
- (BOOL)application: (UIApplication *)application
            openURL: (NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication: (NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation: (id)annotation
{

    if ([[url scheme] isEqualToString:FACEBOOK_SCHEME])
        return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];


    return NO;
}
```

And you have to add URL schemes in target settings->Info->Url Types

[image]